# How can i play a sound via to AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, audio

What is the ActionScript 3 code that will play a sound from the library when a function is executed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
soundClip = new Sound();
soundClip.load(new URLRequest("path"));
soundClip.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, soundLoaded);
soundClip.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, soundLoading);

function soundLoaded(e:Event) {
  soundClip.play();
}

function soundLoading(e:Event) {
  //do something else
}
```

it's like a movieclip .